# Populate tableView with events from iOS (swift)

Tags: swift, ios8, tableview, eventkit

I've been following "iOS8 Swift Programming Cookbook"'s section on EventKit and calendars, and I've learned a lot (especially since I'm new to programming). But the next step that I want to take is populating a tableview that I have an outlet to in my ViewController with the event data so as to have a tableview list of upcoming events. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Here's what I have so far:

```
import UIKit
import EventKit
import EventKitUI


class TodayViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

var events: AnyObject = []

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    requestCalendarAccess()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func requestCalendarAccess() {

    let eventStore = EKEventStore()


    switch EKEventStore.authorizationStatusForEntityType(EKEntityTypeEvent){

    case .Authorized:
        readEvents()
    case .Denied:
        displayAccessDenied()
    case .NotDetermined:
        eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityTypeEvent, completion:
            {[weak self] (granted: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if granted{
                    self!.readEvents()
                } else {
                    self!.displayAccessDenied()
                }
        })
    case .Restricted:
        displayAccessRestricted()
    }
}


func displayAccessDenied(){
    println("Access to the event store is denied.")
}

func displayAccessRestricted(){
    println("Access to the event store is restricted.")
}

func readEvents(){

    /* Instantiate the event store */
    let eventStore = EKEventStore()

    let icloudSource = sourceInEventStore(eventStore,
        type: EKSourceTypeCalDAV,
        title: "iCloud")

    if icloudSource == nil{
        println("You have not configured iCloud for your device.")
        return
    }

    let calendar = calendarWithTitle("Work",
        type: EKCalendarTypeCalDAV,
        source: icloudSource!,
        eventType: EKEntityTypeEvent)

    if calendar == nil{
        println("Could not find the calendar we were looking for.")
        return
    }

    /* The event starts from today, right now */
    let startDate = NSDate()

    /* The end date will be 1 day from today */
    let endDate = startDate.dateByAddingTimeInterval(24 * 60 * 60)

    /* Create the predicate that we can later pass to the
    event store in order to fetch the events */
    let searchPredicate = eventStore.predicateForEventsWithStartDate(
        startDate,
        endDate: endDate,
        calendars: [calendar!])

    /* Fetch all the events that fall between
    the starting and the ending dates */
    let events = eventStore.eventsMatchingPredicate(searchPredicate)
        as [EKEvent]

    if events.count == 0 {
        println("No events could be found")
    } else {

        // Go through all the events and print them to the console
        for event in events{

            println("Event title = \(event.title)")
            println("Event start date = \(event.startDate)")
            println("Event end date = \(event.endDate)")
        }
    }

}

func sourceInEventStore(
    eventStore: EKEventStore,
    type: EKSourceType,
    title: String) -> EKSource?{

        for source in eventStore.sources() as [EKSource]{
            if source.sourceType.value == type.value &&
                source.title.caseInsensitiveCompare(title) ==
                NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame{
                    return source
            }
        }

        return nil
}

func calendarWithTitle(
    title: String,
    type: EKCalendarType,
    source: EKSource,
    eventType: EKEntityType) -> EKCalendar?{

        for calendar in source.calendarsForEntityType(eventType).allObjects
            as [EKCalendar]{
                if calendar.title.caseInsensitiveCompare(title) ==
                    NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame &&
                    calendar.type.value == type.value{
                        return calendar
                }
        }

        return nil
}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return events.count
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    cellForRowAtIndexPath
    indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell =
        tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")
            as UITableViewCell


        cell.textLabel!.text = /*what goes here?*/
        return cell
}
```

Right now my events are printing to the console perfectly, but I'm not sure how to get from there to the tableview in my view controller. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at first your event data should be accessible in you table delegate

```
func readEvents(){
...
let events = eventStore.eventsMatchingPredicate(searchPredicate)
        as [EKEvent]
...
}
```

but events are NOT !!!
you fetch your data just locally in you function readEvents
eventhough you declare a store for events in your class, you never filled it

```
class TodayViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
var events: AnyObject = []
...
}
```

to fill the data in you class variable just remove 'redeclaration'

```
    ...
    var events: [EKEvent] = []    

    func readEvents(){
        ...
        events = eventStore.eventsMatchingPredicate(searchPredicate)
                as [EKEvent]
        ...
     }
```

Comment: I removed the redeclaration, but when I try to populate the tableview with cell.textlabel!.text = event.eventIdentifier (per @beeef's instruction) I am still getting no events in my tableview when I run the app on my iPhone.

Comment: where event.eventIdentifier is going from? check your 'printing' in fetch function. i can see there title, startDate, endDate ...

Comment: I can see all of the event info in the console, but I can't get it to appear in my tableview...

Comment: cell.textLabel!.text = /*what goes here?*/ events[indexPath.row].title

will set the label text in your cell to title of event
for further you have to follow some beginers tutorial or apple documentation

Comment: I must have an error somewhere else then? because this is not populating the tableview.

Comment: I tried println(events) and nothing printed to the console. does that mean that I have an error somewhere in populating the events array?

Comment: if your events array is empty, nothing will be shown in your table view, that is correct. but! if you didn't change nothing else in your code as i suggested to you, the console should show the same result

Answer (score 0):

The function

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

gets passed the parameter *cellForRowAtIndexPath* which contains the index of the row inside your tableview. You can access that index using *indexPath.row*, which you should use to access your *events*-Array.

So for example your function could look like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

    var event = self.events[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel!.text = event.eventIdentifier

    return cell
}
```

I don't know exactly how the EKEvent Class looks like, but Apple's Documentation of that class says there is the *eventIdentifier* of type *String* and so you can take that to test it with your tableview.

Hope you enjoy programming! :)

Comment: Hmm.. I tried that, but the tableview isn't populating at all.

Comment: I have removed the 'redeclaration' according to @user3441734's recommendations. But still have no events filling the tableview. I have 6 events that populate the console just fine.